# Не могу исправить ошибку в реализации quicksort

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Если я правильно понял проблему, то она заключается в том, что я не ставлю некоторые числа на правильное место. Но я не знаю, как исправить эту проблему.

```
std::vector<int>::iterator partition(std::vector<int>::iterator left,
                                     std::vector<int>::iterator right, 
                                     int elem) {
    // Проверка вроде как бесполезная, но все же поставил
    if (left == right) {
        return left;
    }
    while (left != right) {
        // двигаю левый итератор до того момента, пока он меньше elem
        while (*left < elem) {
            ++left;
            if (left == right)
                return left;
        }
        // Двигаю правый итератор, пока он меньше elem. 
        // Проблема скорее всего здесь, так как случай равенства elem не обрабатывается
        while (*right > elem) {
            --right;
            if (right == left)
                return right;
        }
        // Если итераторы не совпали, значения итераторов меняются и цикл продолжается
        if (left != right) {
            std::swap(*left, *right);
            ++left;
        }
    }
    return left;
}


void quicksort(std::vector<int>::iterator left, std::vector<int>::iterator right) {
    if (left >= right) {
        return;
    }
    // Выбираю рандомный элемент из массива
    auto elem = rand() % (right - left) + left;
    // Соответственно опорный элемент, относительно которого массив будет делиться на части
    std::vector<int>::iterator pivot = partition(left, right, *elem);
    // Рекурсивные вызовы. Возможно, проблему можно исправить здесь, делая 
    // std::swap(elem, pivot) и quickosort(left, pivot). То есть элемент, 
    // относительно которого все раскидалось будет в конце и массив поделиться относительно elem'a.
    quicksort(left, pivot - 1);
    quicksort(pivot + 1, right);
}

int main() {
    size_t N = 0;
    std::cin >> N;
    std::vector<int> array(N);
    for (size_t i = 0; i != N; ++i) {
        std::cin >> array[i];
    }
    if (N != 0)
        quicksort(array.begin(), array.end() - 1);
    for (auto elem : array) {
        std::cout << elem << " ";
    }
}
```

Например:

7

7 7 7 -1 3 -1 -1 -> -1 -1 -1 7 3 7 7 (не понимаю, почему 3 оказалась именно там)

Или

6

-4 2 3 1 4 3 -> -4 1 3 2 3 4

Comment: В `partition()` после `swap` добавьте еще и `--right`. /  А для эффективности (как мне кажется) можно еще перед вызовом partition поменять случайный elem со средним в массиве.

Comment: @avp я специально убрал этот момент, так как right может уйти левее left и будет бесконечный цикл.

Comment: А, только сейчас заметил `!=` -- обычно там пишут `whilе (left <= right)`. Да и циклы, в которых сдвигают left и right, стараются делать максимально короткими. Впрочем, лучше посто посмотрите нормальное (например, как у Кнута) описание алгоритма с его анализом, как правильно выбирать pivot и в каком порядке сортировать подмассивы после выбора pivot и почему тут лучше делать итерацию, а не рекурсию и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: Вот здесь `quicksort(pivot + 1, right);` тоже ошибка. Нужно `quicksort(pivot, right);`.

Comment: @avp тогда возникает бесконечный вызов второй функции на некоторых данных. Например:5
1 5 2 4 3

Comment: Значит для  случая `left == right` в `partiton()` надо возвращать left + 1 / И еще момент, вот тут `auto elem = rand() % (right - left) + left;` выбирается elem из отрезка без последнего элемента. left -- первый, right -- последний, значит количество элементов  = right - left + 1

Comment: @avp, да, вы правы, большое спасибо. Можно ли как-то ускорить алгоритм?

Comment: Для начала сделайте итеративным (эмулируйте стек для left/right размером log N (при правильном подходе этого достаточно))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. `elem` никогда не выбирается последний
2. Нужно включить `pivot` в правый интервал, ведь он ещё не встал на своё место.
   у тебя `elem` всегда попадает в левую часть, а pivot - это просто место встречи. После такого `partition` гарантируется только:

> `[0, pivot)` <= `elem`
>   `[pivot, last]` > `elem`

В общем:

```
 void quicksort(std::vector<int>::iterator left, std::vector<int>::iterator right) {
    if (left >= right) {
        return;
    }
    auto elem = rand() % (right - left + 1) + left; // <- тут

    std::vector<int>::iterator pivot = partition(left, right, *elem);

    quicksort(left, pivot - 1);
    quicksort(pivot, right); // <- и тут
}
```

---

Я заинлайнил `partition`(более каноничный), может и не стоит его выделять?

```
void quicksort(std::vector<int>::iterator left, std::vector<int>::iterator right) {
    auto elem = rand() % (right - left + 1) + left;
    //
    auto i = left, j = right;
    while (i <= j) {
        while (*i < *elem) ++i;
        while (*j > *elem) --j;
        if (i <= j) std::swap(*i++, *j--);
    }
    //
    if (left < j)  quicksort(left, j);
    if (i < right) quicksort(i, right);
}
```

Comment: ваша реализация хороша, но не очень понятно, почему он должен возвращать два итератора. Мой инвариант partition - это то, что слева от отправленного elem все элементы меньше, а справа больше. Разве это не гарантирует того, что массив поделится и будет уменьшаться на части? (Скорее всего я что-то не понимаю).

Comment: Массив-то поделится, но вот только не совсем так, как ожидается. Я описал в пункте 2 поведение.